Exception in thread "main" io.restassured.path.json.exception.JsonPathException: Failed to parse the JSON document
I am hitting the GET API request, but I am getting the multiple line error messages, first of the error message says "Exception in thread "main" io.restassured.path.json.exception.JsonPathException: Failed to parse the JSON document"
Code:
import io.restassured.RestAssured;
import io.restassured.path.json.JsonPath;

import static io.restassured.RestAssured.*;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.*;

import files.payload;

public class Basics {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
//validate the add place API working fine or not
        
        RestAssured.baseURI= "https://rahulshettyacademy.com" ;
    String response=given().log().all().queryParam("Key", "=qaclick123").header("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8")
        .body(payload.AddPlace()).post("maps/api/place/add/json")
        .then().assertThat().statusCode(200).body("scope", equalTo("APP"))
        .header("Server", "Apache/2.4.52 (Ubuntu)").extract().response().asString();
    
        System.out.println(response);
        JsonPath js=new JsonPath(response); //for parsing Json
    String placeId=js.getString("place_id");
    String addressJsonString = js.getString("address"); 
    
    System.out.println(placeId);
    System.out.println("Address:"+addressJsonString);   
    
    //update place
    
String newAddress = "Summer Walk, Africa";
    
    given().log().all().queryParam("Key","qaclick123").header("Content-Type", "application/json")
    .body("{\r\n"
            + "\"place_id\":\""+placeId+"\",\r\n"
            + "\"address\":\""+newAddress+"\",\r\n"
            + "\"key\":\"qaclick123\"\r\n"
            + "}").
    when().put("maps/api/place/update/json")
    .then().assertThat().log().all().statusCode(200).body("msg", equalTo("Address successfully updated"));
    
    //Get Place
    
String getPlaceResponse= given().log().all().queryParam("Key", "qaclick123")
    .queryParam("place_id",placeId) 
    .when().get("maps/api/place/get/json")
    .then().assertThat().log().all().statusCode(200)
    .extract().response().asString(); 

JsonPath js1 = new JsonPath(getPlaceResponse);
String actualAddress = js1.getString("newAddress");
System.out.println(actualAddress);
        
    }
}

Error Message:
Exception in thread "main" io.restassured.path.json.exception.JsonPathException: Failed to parse the JSON document
    at io.restassured.path.json.JsonPath$ExceptionCatcher.invoke(JsonPath.java:1002)
    at io.restassured.path.json.JsonPath$4.doParseWith(JsonPath.java:967)
    at io.restassured.path.json.JsonPath$JsonParser.parseWith(JsonPath.java:1047)
    at io.restassured.path.json.JsonPath.get(JsonPath.java:202)
    at io.restassured.path.json.JsonPath.getString(JsonPath.java:352)
    at Basics.main(Basics.java:53)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The JSON input text should neither be null nor empty.
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:73)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:57)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:263)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:277)
    at io.restassured.internal.path.json.ConfigurableJsonSlurper.parseText(ConfigurableJsonSlurper.groovy:80)
    at io.restassured.path.json.JsonPath$4$1.method(JsonPath.java:965)
    at io.restassured.path.json.JsonPath$ExceptionCatcher.invoke(JsonPath.java:1000)
    ... 5 more

JSOn text:
package files;
public class payload {
public String AddPlace() {

    
    
    
      return "{\r\n" + "  \"location\": {\r\n" + "    \"lat\": -38.383494,\r\n" +
      "    \"lng\": 33.427362\r\n" + "  },\r\n" + "  \"accuracy\": 50,\r\n" +
      "  \"name\": \"Frontline house\",\r\n" +
      "  \"phone_number\": \"(+91) 983 893 3937\",\r\n" +
      "  \"address\": \"29, side layout, cohen 09\",\r\n" + "  \"types\": [\r\n" +
      "    \"shoe park\",\r\n" + "    \"shop\"\r\n" + "  ],\r\n" +
      "  \"website\": \"http://google.com\",\r\n" +
      "  \"language\": \"French-IN\"\r\n" + "}";
     
    
    
     

}
}
I hit the GET api request, it was supposed to give me the result

"The JSON input text should neither be null nor empty." would imply that your GET request's response wasn't proper JSON, for one reason or another.

this is the JSON text I am passing
